# TestDriven.NET coverage for a 64-bit app

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2013, nunit, 32bit-64bit, testdriven.net

When I run TestDriven.NET against my NUnit tests, all tests pass.

When I build in 32-bit mode and run TestDriven.NET with Coverage, I get meaningful results.

However, when Coverage option is selected, I get the following message:

```
Can't execute with profiler in 64-bit process. Assembly won't execute in 32-bit process.
```

Is there anything I can do to get past this problem?